# Animate MakeHuman character with BVH using Three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, blender

I'm trying to animate a mesh via it's skeleton on a webpage using a BVH. Here's the overall process of what I'm trying to do:

1. Make a character using MakeHuman and export (mhx format? seems to work best).
2. Import the character into Blender.
3. Retarget to a BVH using the MakeWalk plugin for Blender.
4. Export the character to json using the Three.js exporter.
5. Export the BVH (not sure if this is necessary, but I figured I might have better luck getting the BVH to match up with the skeleton after retargeting)
6. Load the character into a web page using Three.js
7. Animate the character using a BVH.

The animation looks great in blender. I'm trying to use the **[JavaScript BVH viewer code from here](http://lo-th.github.io/olympe/BVH_player.html)** modified to use the skeleton created by MakeHuman instead of it creating a skeleton from the BVH data. Whenever I try to animate the character, it gets very distorted.

Here's the desired result (more or less) rendered from Blender:

[image: desired result]

And this is what is happening on the webpage:

[image: buggy result]

As you can see, it's getting totally messed up. I also had to zoom way out in order to see the whole image.

I've tried using different rigs, different file formats, resaving the BVH after retargeting, you name it. I also tried to follow the example [here](https://gameportalen.com/three.js_Skeleton_animation_Makehuman_export/MakeHuman7.html) (scroll down to see the instructions), but it says to delete the armature modifiers and when I do that, no bones get exported and Three.js throws an error.

I am at a loss. Is there an up-to-date example somewhere that shows how to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: What is BVH? I have no idea?

Comment: It's a file format for motion capture. The BVH viewer parses the file with javascript and then animates the character using the data. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biovision_Hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me when I exported from Blender to Three.js.
The solution that worked for me was (after step 3 in your list) to ensure in Blender that there were no object rotations still that hadnt been applied (ctrl-a). In other word the skeleton and the mesh must have no additional rotations or scaling.

Comment: I tried that, resetting location, rotation, scale, etc.. but unfortunately that wasn't what is causing this problem.

Comment: It really looks like there is a scaling problem which makes me think that either you tried to scale the armature or you scaled the mesh and didnt apply it before you exported it. Alternatively it could be the version of the Three.js exporter\blender version you are using. Things worked for me in 2.73.

Comment: That's the same link that I posted in my question. As I said, it says to delete the modifiers, but when I do that no bones get exported. Those instructions probably only work for an older version of Three.js.